# Symfony 4 global route prefix

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing, symfony4

I can't find any info about the global route prefix in a Symfony 4 application. The only [thing](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-prefix-all-controller-route-names) I've found is annotating the controllers with `@route`. But I don't use annotations and I need all the controllers to have the same prefix.

Now I could do that in S3 like this in the `app/config/routing.yml` file:

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix: /foo
```

But S4 is bundleless and I can't do the same - I would have to create a bundle which I don't need.

Is it possible to define a global route prefix in Symfony 4 at all or I'm going to end up with prefixing every single root/creating a custom route loader, especially if I configure routes in YAML?

Answer (score 8):

This works *with* annotations, giving every controller 'this/prefix' :

```
# file: config/routes/annotations.yaml

controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix: this/prefix
```

Then for imported routes 'this/prefix' gets applied to all of FOSUserBundle's routes below (yes I tested it).

```
# file: config/routes.yaml

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
    prefix: this/prefix
```

If you are not using annotations you should be able to import your separate routing file (which can import many more) applying the prefix to everything in the resource. But drop the "@" notation and use relative path to your file.
The value of 'this/prefix' can be configured as a **Service Container Parameter**, look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/service_container_parameters.html

Answer (score 6):

I'm probably not understanding the question because I don't know why you would want a global prefix in your app.  You can set a prefix when importing a route file even if you are using yaml and no bundles.

```
# config/routes.yaml
blog:
    resource: '../src/Resources/config/routes/blog.yaml'
    prefix: blog

# src/Resources/config/routes/blog.yaml
blog_show:
    path: /show
    controller: App\Controller\BlogController::show

blog_list:
    path: /list
    controller: App\Controller\BlogController::list
```

bin/console debug:router would yield

```
blog_show          ANY      ANY      ANY    /blog/show     
blog_list          ANY      ANY      ANY    /blog/list
```

But again, I suspect you are asking for something else.  Perhaps you could add an example to your question?

Comment: I have a backend webserver rewriting requests to different microservices mounted to the webserver depending on the first segment in the URI, so that _https://backend/account/foo/bar is rewritten to the account microservice, _https://backend/media/foo/bar is rewritten to the media microservice. That's why I need the /account and /media prefiexes, the final apps get the original path. Maybe it can be done any better way.

Comment: Sorry but I still have no idea what you are asking for.  Hopefully, someone else will come by with a better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve prefix to any route. They differ mainly due to the route type they target.

For **routes defined by annotations** you need to edit `config/routes/annotations.yaml`
and put there `prefix: your-prefix` key-value pair.

For **routes defined by YAML list** you need to edit `config/routes.yaml` put there under a new route `prefix: your-prefix` key-value pair and `resource: "routes/routes-that-you-want-to-be-prefixed.yaml"` and create the file `routes/routes-that-you-want-to-be-prefixed.yaml` that has all the routes then remove all routes from `config/routes.yaml` besides that one which uses `resource: "routes/routes-that-you-want-to-be-prefixed.yaml"`.

You may also use quick and dirty approach if you're in hurry and want to check prefixing. Edit `src/Kernel.php` and suffix all `$routes->import(..)` with `->prefix('your-prefix)` (no need to change any routing files)

I wrote a comprehensive description with some example code samples as an aswer to that question:
[Running Symfony 5 with reverse proxy in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64112968/1174405)

Example code snippets have been tested against **Symfony 4.4** and **Symfony 5.1** and worked without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and haven't been able to solve it using yaml configuration but I have it working adding an annotation on the top of the class like this:

```
/**
 *
 * Rest\Route("/api")
 */
class TestController extends FosRestController
{
   /**
     * @Rest\Route("/test", name="tm_test")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function testAction()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

That will produce a route `/api/test` for the `testAction()`

Look this post: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-prefix-all-controller-route-names

Hope it helps