# How to add a prefix to many routes in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'd like all my Controller action routes in the namespace 'App\Controller\Api' to have the prefix '/api'. I also want to use annotations inside the controllers to set the rest of the route.

In Symfony 3 this was done by editing 'config/routing.yml':

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/Api'
    type: annotation
    prefix: /api
```

How can I do this in Symfony 4? Do I need to make a bundle? Which config file would I use since I don't have a 'config/routing.yml'?

Comment: You can still import routes and set a prefix without a bundle.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120939/symfony-4-global-route-prefix/48121299#48121299

Comment: I saw that page. I don't understand where Resources comes from or what I need in my 'config/routes.yaml'. I started my project with `composer create-project symfony/skeleton my-project`

Comment: Don't actually need a Resources directory in this case.  Just make a config/routes_api.yaml file and import it.  And your 4.1 link applies to the name of the route not the route itself.  So not applicable.

Comment: @Cerad I failed to mention I want to use annotations to build the route cache. Is config/routes_api.yaml intended to contain routes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok It looks like I should have just tried real path names. The following worked in 'config/routes.yaml':

```
api:
    prefix: /api
    resource: '../src/Controller/Api'
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you use annotations, you may also need to add `type: annotation` here, otherwise `Cannot load resource "../src/Controller/Api"` error may occur.

Comment: I need to add prefix v1 and prefix '' for the same controller.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

At first run `composer require annotations` and then

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
* @Route("/blog")
*/
class BlogController extends Controller
{

}
```

Comment: This is a great example, but It only shows me how to make a single route with the yaml file. I'd like to use the config file to set the prefix for many controllers in a particular namespace and use annotations to set the rest of the route.

Comment: This does work, but then I'm forced to type @Route('/api') manually for every route controller that needs. I even tried extending a class with the prefix and it did not carry over.