# Running Symfony 5 with reverse proxy in subdirectory

Tags: php, symfony

I like to run a Symfony 5 application behind a reverse proxy which supplies the following endpoint:

https://my.domain/service1/

The proxy config basically is this:

```
ProxyPass /marketsy/ http://internal.service1/
```

On the server the reverse proxy is connecting to, I use the following apache rule for serving my Symfony application:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName internal.service1
  DocumentRoot /webroot/service1/public

 <FilesMatch \.php$>
     SetHandler proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm-ui.sock|fcgi://localhost
     SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
     SetEnv HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https"
 </FilesMatch>

 <Directory  /webroot/service1/public>
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
     FallbackResource /index.php
 </Directory>

 <Directory  /webroot/service1/public/bundles>
     FallbackResource disabled
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The application itself is reqachable but Symfony can't hanle the "service1" path prefix.

For example it tries to access the profiler under https://my.domain/_wdt/8e3926 instead of https://my.domain/service1/_wdt/8e3926 and beside the root route all the routing isn't working:

For example:
When I try to access https://my.domain/service1/my/page i will get redirected to https://my.domain/my/page

Now my question is, how can I configure Symfony to know about the "service1" path prefix when generation urls ets.

Comment: The symfony application is not realy in a subfolder, this additional directory is introduced by the reverse proxy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Proper way of doing it (example):

Create `src/Controller/BarController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class BarController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return new Response('<p>Bar controler response</p>');
    }
}
```

and `src/Controller/FooController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class FooController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return new Response('<p>Foo controler response</p>');
    }
}
```

Create `config/routes/prefix-routes.yaml`

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index

bar:
    path: /bar
    controller: App\Controller\BarController::index
 
foo:
    path: /foo
    controller: App\Controller\FooController::index
```

and edit routing `config/routes.yaml` - delete its contents and just put:

```
prefixed:
   resource: "routes/prefix-routes.yaml"
   prefix: service1
```

all of controllers are now available at urls:

```
http://localhost/service1/ for DefaultController.php
http://localhost/service1/bar for BarController.php
http://localhost/service1/foo for FooController.php
```

If you want your profiler to work with `service1` prefix as well then edit `config/routes/dev/web_profiler.yaml` this way:

```
web_profiler_wdt:
    resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml'
    prefix: service1/_wdt

web_profiler_profiler:
    resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml'
    prefix: service1/_profiler
```

now they should be available at:

```
http://localhost/service1/_wdt... for wdt
http://localhost/service1/_profiler for profiler
```

Adding prefix for annotations:

Create controller `src/Controller/AnnoController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AnnoController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/anno", name="anno")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return new Response('<p>Anno controler response</p>');
    }
}
```

edit `config/routes/annotations.yaml` and add `prefix: service1`:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix: service1

kernel:
    resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
    type: annotation
```

Now prefix is added to routes done via annotation:

```
http://localhost/service1/anno for AnnoController.php
```

Some references:

[Symfony Routing Prefix](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-groups-and-prefixes)
[Symfony Routing Configuration Keys](https://alanstorm.com/symfony-routing-configuration-keys/)

**Adding prefix** quick and dirty workaround to add prefix `service1` to all of routing (not recommended).

Instead of changing routing as above just Edit `src/Kernel.php` `protected function configureRoutes`

and change every `$routes->import` line by adding `->prefix('service1')` at the end so it looks this way:

```
protected function configureRoutes(RoutingConfigurator $routes): void
{
    $routes->import('../config/{routes}/'.$this->environment.'/*.yaml')->prefix('service1');
    $routes->import('../config/{routes}/*.yaml')->prefix('service1');

    if (is_file(\dirname(__DIR__).'/config/routes.yaml')) {

        $routes->import('../config/{routes}.yaml')->prefix('service1');

    } elseif (is_file($path = \dirname(__DIR__).'/config/routes.php')) {
        (require $path)($routes->withPath($path), $this);
    }
}
```

all of controllers are now available at urls:

```
http://localhost/service1/ for DefaultController.php
http://localhost/service1/bar for BarController.php
http://localhost/service1/foo for FooController.php
```

as well as the profiler:

```
http://localhost/service1/_wdt... for wdt
http://localhost/service1/_profiler for profiler
```

Comment: Is it also possible for annotation based routes to add a common prefix (somewhere in code or a config file, not in the annotation itself)?

Comment: @Johni Yes, please see updated answer under the section `Adding prefix for annotations`

Comment: Thanks it works now. I also added a kernel request subscriber to add the prefic to the request url since this isn't forwarded by the reverse proxy.

Comment: @Johni I'm glad I could help. Could you please edit your question and add that subscriber as additional solution so all the others in the future having the same problem will have a complete set of example modifications to do?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution @Jimmix provided, I had to write a subscriber to add a prefix to my request path:

```php
<?php namespace My\Bundle\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class AppPrefixSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    /** @var string */
    private $appPrefix;

    public function __construct(?string $appPrefix) {
        $this->appPrefix = $appPrefix;
    }

    /**
     * Returns events to subscribe to
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
                ['onKernelRequest', 3000]
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Adds base url to request based on environment var
     *
     * @param RequestEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event) {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->appPrefix) {
            $request = $event->getRequest();

            $newUri =
                $this->appPrefix .
                $request->server->get('REQUEST_URI');

            $event->getRequest()->server->set('REQUEST_URI', $newUri);
            $request->initialize(
                $request->query->all(),
                $request->request->all(),
                $request->attributes->all(),
                $request->cookies->all(),
                $request->files->all(),
                $request->server->all(),
                $request->getContent()
            );
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Symfony 5.3 there is no need to modify the requests paths manually by an event subscriber or by changing route prefixes, as symfony now supports the `X-Forwarded-Prefix` HTTP header. When the Reverse proxy pass this header to the symfony application, then the base URL of the Request object is correctly set and all generated paths get automatically prefixed.

In apache, you can use `mod_header` to add the header, by adding a `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Prefix "/marketsys"` (or like) directive to vhost configuration.

Be sure that `X-Forwared-Prefix` is configured as trusted header, if you want to use this feature.